# Android: manifest package name for Google Play Store

Tags: android, package-name

I have developed an app that has a package name in the manifest called:

> com.android.example.XXXXXXXXXXXX.

I took a sample from google and added my own code onto it.

Stupidly, I did not changed my package name to something like the reverse order of my website which is what it is suppose to look like. I have registered multiple API keys (GCM keys for cloud messaging etc) based on this package name.

However, I'm sure that what I have put as my XXXXXXXX portion of the package name is quite unique and there is very little chance that it should be registered by anyone else.

To change the package name would mean re-registering all these API keys using the new package name which can be quite a lot of work. Also the package name will not be displayed on the Play Store- its more to uniquely identify my app on the Play Store's internally.

Is changing the package name worthwhile to do before I upload an app to the Play Store?

Comment: I would, for trademark violation reasons, if nothing else. "Also the package name will not be displayed on the Play Store" -- yes, it is, in the URL.

Comment: You do not get to change the package in Google Play.

Comment: Oh - I only noticed that now. Angry Birds one is : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rovio.angrybirds

Comment: I think it also gives a false impression to user when they see com.example.asdfasdfasdfasd. In my opinion it is worth to make it right.

Comment: It is also great luck that are not banned )